# Processing OCRed text

Tags: c#, antlr, ocr, text-processing

I am extracting texts from OCRed Tiff files by using a library and dumping it in database. The text I am extracting are actually FORMS having fields like NAME,DOB,COUNTRY etc. Since OCR does not the difference between actual value and the label,it's just dumping all text. Now I have text in DB in following format:

Name:    MyName
Address:   My Address

etc

Now the next step is to extract values lile **MyName** and **MyAddrss** from the DB. The document types may varry hence a generic parser might not work.

What would you suggest to deal this situation? Should I write different parsers? may ANTLR can help me? if yes then how? Kindly guide me.

I am working on .NET

Comment: by that mean that one document could be a "leave application form" while other could be 'Training Request' form. Both could have different fields